# How should I prepare a wall painted with sandpaint and construction adhesive?

Tags: drywall

I have a section of wall that was painted with sand paint.  It also had paneling halfway up the wall that was adhered with construction adhesive.  My goal is to have a smooth, flat wall, and paint it.  I also want to move an electrical switch and add an electrical outlet.

How can I best prepare the wall?

Comment: I think I have two options: 1) remove the existing drywall. 2) go over the existing drywall with new drywall.  I think either way i'm going to hang new drywall.  I don't see scraping or sanding as an option.  I don't know if there's any cons to leaving the old drywall in place.  It's not moldy and except for a 2 sq. ft. section it's in good shape.  It's an insulated interior wall so running the electric is going to be pain if i leave the old stuff up.

Comment: Well, since that was what I was going to answer before I saw you'd figured it out in a comment, post it as an answer - perfectly fine to answer your own questions on SE. Classic case of the common drywall situation where rip and replace is faster and cheaper (if briefly messy) than trying to fix what's already there.

Comment: Depends how bad it is and how good you want it.  Heavy texture can cover a multitude of sins.  Tearing it out and hanging new stuff is most likely to give you the finish you want though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the existing drywall or go over the existing drywall with new drywall.  Depending how much electrical work you want to do or if there's any insulation work to be done.